# XAMPP V3.2.1 -MySQL throwing error

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

I have installed the XAMPPv3.2.1 for PHP development.Since I have installed Skype and its using the Port 80 and 443 ,I configured XAMPP to run on ports 1333(http.conf) and 3333(https.conf).

I started the xampp MySQL service and started successfully.

When I navigate to http://:1333 xampp is working fine ,However if I click on phpmyadmin i am getting the following error.

MySQL said: Documentation

## 2002 - An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.

The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).

Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.

can anybody help me in resolving this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you also change the port in the `phpmyadmin.conf` file?

Comment: No,I did not change port in phpmyadmin.conf file,What needs to be changed in this conf file

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me with all the **default settings** of xampp:

1. Quit skype
2. Quit skype
3. Run xampp again. It should now start again
4. (optional) run skype again

Hope this helps.